# How to get the current project folder path?

Tags: c#

How to get the current project folder path?

```
    string str = Application.ExecutablePath;
    string scriptpath = Directory.GetParent(str).Parent.FullName;

C:\Users\<My User Name>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\MyFolder\MyFolder2\MyFolder3\file.exe
```

returns -> Folder Path with .exe file on it.

This syntax : Directory.GetParent(str).Parent.FullName returns the folder path ..
    C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\MyFolder\MyFolder2\

I am not able to get the `"  C:\Users\<My User Name>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\MyFolder\MyFolder2\MyFolder3\ "`

I need to get the folder path above the .exe file.

Comment: You're asking for the *application's* directory, not the current directory.

Comment: Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.FullName: You are going up two directory, is that where your scripts are? Also, are file's kept at that location? And I assume file exists there?

Comment: Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.FullName  syntax returns the directory excluding bin / debug folder path  such as c:\MyProject\  and then i am concatenating the SQL Script folder path and so it become as c:\MyProject\SQLScripts\DBScript.sql    - This works fine from Development env / Debug mode.